# ArrayList skipping an index

Tags: java

I want my array to skip blank indexes. This is the format of the text file.

```
some text

1
2
3
4

2
5
4
6

5
7
6
8
```

Here's my code

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
class ArrayPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")); //reads the file
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //creates arraylist
        String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){ 
                        //i thought this just reads the lines and if its null skips it but its not happening
         list.add(line);
    }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(list);
        if (list.get(2).equals(list.get(5))){ //comparing two of the lines that should be equal
            System.out.println("Should be equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println(list.get(3));
            System.out.println(list.get(7));
            System.out.println("This is what is actually equal from my code")
        }
            System.out.println(list.size()); //says the size of the list is 16
}
}
```

I thought the way I set up how my code adds lines ignores the blank ones. Also wondering why the size of the list is 16 when there are only 15 indexes. My question is how do I ignore blank lines of text in my file.

Comment: If you want to skip blank lines, you should check if `!line.isEmpty()` before you add it. The check `!=null` is to end your loop completely, not to skip blank lines.

Comment: You could test to see if the trimmed line is empty before adding it: `if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) list.add(line);`

Comment: There are 16 lines in your text (empty lines are lines too). And as many other languages, Java numbers elements from 0. So the valid indexes are 0...15.

Comment: To add to the previous comments, BufferedReader.readLine() returns null upon reaching EOF (end of file). So, if you take all comments into account, you should be able to come up with a working solution now :-)

Comment: Theres only 15 lines in the text file there is no line after the last "filled" line

Comment: But thank you all for the advice im trying these methods now

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){  
     list.add(line);
}
```

This only checks whether the read line is null ornot. By definition a line is only null when the last line has been read.
Empty lines are represented by empty strings. In order to skip those you have to check whether the line is empty.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){  
     if(!line.isEmpty()) {
          list.add(line);
     } 
}
```

You could trim the lines if they could contain spaces you want to avoid.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){  
     if(!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
          list.add(line);
     } 
}
```

Comment: thanks again I got the array to not add the blank lines

Comment: You're welcome. Consider marking this as an answer to your question.